# PostGis - Split polygon into two based in point

Tags: postgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

[image]

How I split this **single** polygon into **two** polygons based on the point where there is an intersection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `st_makeValid` to transform the invalid source into a multipolygon, then `st_dump` to transform the multipolygon into two simple polygons

```sql
with src(geom) as (values ('polygon((0 0, 10 0,0 10, 10 10, 0 0))'::geometry))
select st_asText(
         (st_dump(
           st_makeValid(geom,'method=structure'))
         ).geom) 
from src;
           st_astext
-------------------------------
 POLYGON((5 5,0 10,10 10,5 5))
 POLYGON((0 0,5 5,10 0,0 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working perfectly.